# Unable to compile Substrate v0.9.17 on Rust v1.60.0

Tags: compilation

I am not able to compile Substrate v0.9.17 on Rust version 1.60.0 stable. I am getting the following compilation error. It was working before I did `rustup update`. I missed recording which Rust version I was using when it was working.

```
  error: the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
     --> /Users/gautham/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.6/src/lib.rs:235:9
      |
  235 | /         compile_error!("the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by \
  236 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  237 | |                         For more information see: \
  238 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
      | |________________________________________________________________________^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
     --> /Users/gautham/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.6/src/lib.rs:262:5
      |
  262 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
      |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
  error: could not compile `getrandom` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Comment: Dupe of https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/529/failed-to-resolve-use-of-undeclared-crate-or-module-imp ?

Comment: It is not a duplicate, the error is due to an improper rust version and probably needs a fix in the upstream dependencies of Substrate.

Comment: This stack exchange is not for solving individual compile errors. This bug is also already fixed in master: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/4bc2af13cd81007a2a340d0333062179420d5daf

Comment: @bkchr I understand that, but the solution to the linked question is not an appropriate solution to my question. I believe the commit link shared by you is correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found that using this specific Rust version, `nightly-2022-01-01` allows me to compile it without any change in the codebase.

EDIT

As shared by bkchr in the comments the issue is [fixed upstream](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/4bc2af13cd81007a2a340d0333062179420d5daf) and can be resolved by fetching the latest version of substrate.

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue. What do you mean by "fetching the latest version of substrate"? Just include `sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }` in `Cargo.toml` or what? I'm currently working on node template which I cloned on 9th of April

Comment: I was able to solve it by working with the master branch. If I remember correctly, the fix for this is not included in branch polkadot-v0.9.19