# cannot find module 'sys' and ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

Tags: pallet, crates

I have this error. Please check out the code at https://github.com/nhathuyenqt/pos-node

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/h/Desktop/pokadot/pos-node/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/h/Desktop/pokadot/pos-node/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-cd1339cedb99f0d8/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: env -u CARGO_ENCODED_RUSTFLAGS -u CARGO_TARGET_DIR RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/Users/h/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/h/Desktop/pokadot/pos-node/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.76.0-nightly (ba7c7a301 2023-11-13)


  --- stderr
     Compiling getrandom v0.2.12
  error: the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
     --> /Users/h/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/getrandom-0.2.12/src/lib.rs:291:9
      |
  291 | /         compile_error!("the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by \
  292 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  293 | |                         For more information see: \
  294 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
      | |________________________________________________________________________^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
     --> /Users/h/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/getrandom-0.2.12/src/lib.rs:347:9
      |
  347 |         imp::getrandom_inner(dest)?;
      |         ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
  error: could not compile `getrandom` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
```

I even tried the solution from here: [failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/529/failed-to-resolve-use-of-undeclared-crate-or-module-imp)
but it does not really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is almost always about missing `default-features = false` or not enabling `std` feature for the dependency.

in your case, in `pallet-template` `sp-core`, `sp-io`, `log` are missing `default-features = false` and `std` is not enabled for several others. Carefully look at the dependencies and make sure they are properly included.

Comment: how to check it via ``cargo tree``

Comment: not sure about that, but you can use `cargo-featalign` to check for missing features https://github.com/hack-ink/cargo-featalign